# Como fazer busca MYSQL procurar palavra no titulo e depois no texto e ordenar pelo titulo primeiro

Tags: mysql, select, where

Tenho uma tabela com titulo e conteúdo e queria fazer uma busca para ver se o termo está em algum desses campos.

Se tiver, trazer primeiro os resultados do titulo e depois do conteúdo

```
tabela
id|titulo|conteudo
1 |abc   |oai poa
2 |aaa   |abc
3 |abc   |xcvv
4 |ttt   |rt d
```

no exemplo acima, numa busca por `"abc"` gostaria de trazer primeiro os ids `1` e `2` e por ultimo o `3`, que não tem abc no titulo, mas tem no conteúdo. E como segundo critério de ordem, colocar em ordem alfabetica, sei fazer apenas usando 1 critério:

```
SELECT titulo
FROM tabela
WHERE titulo LIKE '%abc%'
ORDER BY titulo ASC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu faria parecido com o que o Arthur fez, só que atribundo a importancia do resultado a um valor. Por exemplo:

- Se houver resultado no título atribui ao resultado 2
- Se houver resultado no conteúdo atribui ao resultado 1
- Soma tudo, e coloca em ordem decrescente ( DA MAIOR RELEVÂNCIA PARA A
  MENOR)

O Select ficaria assim:

```
SELECT
   titulo, id
FROM
   tabela
WHERE 
    titulo   LIKE '%abc%' 
 OR conteudo LIKE '%abc%' 

ORDER BY (
    CASE WHEN `titulo` LIKE '%abc%'
    THEN 2 # título é o mais importante então o valor é 2
    ELSE 0
    END
  ) + (
    CASE WHEN `conteudo` LIKE '%abc%'
    THEN 1 # conteúdo é o segundo mais importante então o valor é 1
    ELSE 0
    END
  ) DESC;
```

Após o comentário **"Ah, mais uma coisa, há itens quem tem o termo no titulo e no conteúdo, nesse caso, priorizar titulo"**

Meste caso você pode fazer algo assim:

```
SELECT
   titulo, id
FROM
   tabela
WHERE 
    titulo   LIKE '%abc%' 
 OR conteudo LIKE '%abc%' 

ORDER BY (
    CASE WHEN `titulo` LIKE '%abc%' AND `conteudo` NOT LIKE '%abc%' 
    THEN 2 # título é o mais importante então o valor é 2
    ELSE 0
    END
  ) + (
    CASE WHEN `conteudo` LIKE '%abc%' AND `titulo` NOT LIKE '%abc%' 
    THEN 1 # conteúdo é o segundo mais importante então o valor é 1
    ELSE 0
    END
  ) + (
    CASE WHEN `conteudo` LIKE '%abc%' AND `titulo` LIKE '%abc%' 
    THEN 2 # valor é 2 pois a relevância é o título
    ELSE 0
    END
  ) DESC
```

Comment: show, esse deu certo tbm!!!

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar valores booleanos no order, a expressão é avaliada em 0 no caso da clausula ser falsa e 1 caso seja verdadeira.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591608/using-boolean-expression-in-order-by-clause?rq=1

Dessa forma a Query fica assim:

```
SELECT
   titulo
FROM
   tabela
WHERE 
    titulo   LIKE '%abc%'
 OR conteudo LIKE '%abc%'

ORDER BY (titulo LIKE '%abc%') ASC, titulo ASC
```

Comment: ele trouxe todos, mas trouxe invertido, primeiro vieram os que tem no conteudo e por ultimo os que tem no titulo. Ah, mais uma coisa, há itens quem tem o termo no titulo e no conteudo, nesse caso, priorizar titulo

Comment: Nesse caso acredito que seja só colocar ASC no booleano do order (já corrigi na resposta). Da forma que está ele já prioriza título, pois ele vai avaliar (titulo LIKE '%abc%') como verdeiro mesmo se o conteúdo também o for.

Comment: deu certo, só alterar asc por desc

Comment: Então Arthur, não está dando certo este select, veja > http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35e0c8/1

Comment: Quem está em primeiro é justamente o 'aaa' e deveria ser os 'abc' da vida...

Comment: Assim funciona > http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e1ccd/3